# Using Firebase, firebase.auth().currentUser is a null value even though it is being logged

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I created a query that is in a service.TS file that shows an items "state" that is based on a logged in user's UID:

```
getLists(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {console.log("blah", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    // User is signed in.
  }
});
  return this.db.list('/foods', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'state/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'/state',
      equalTo: 'listed'
    }
  });
}
```

Using this query, I'm getting an error that reads:

Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_firebase_app**"auth".curren‌​tUser.uid').

Using `{console.log("blah", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)`, which you can see above, correctly displays the UID in the log, confirming that the user is signed in.

I'm not sure if it's relevant but this query is being called by the page's main TS file with:

```
    ngOnInit() {

    this.moviesSvc.getLists()
                  .subscribe(lists => {console.log(lists); console.log("UID", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid); this.lists = lists})
  }
```

What do I need to do to correctly pass the UID to the query?

Answer (score 3):

[onAuthStateChanged()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) is asynchronous, so when you have the user `uid` in its callback, then only perform your operation, like this:

```
getLists(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {

    var self = this;

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            var userID = user.uid;

            return self.db.list('/foods', {
                query: {
                    orderByChild: 'state/' + userID + '/state',
                    equalTo: 'listed'
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: This gives me an error showing: _A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value_. I'm also getting the error: _TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.db.list')_ and _Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.moviesSvc.getLists() .subscribe')_.

Comment: @cfoster5 updated the code, the 'this' inside callback would be different, so cache it as self and use it..

Comment: Trying this still comes with the errors listed above.