# Firebase rtdb cannot bind value in constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

In constructor of my service i expect to set dynamic path to database, depending on user id(uid)

```
 private dbPath = '/pages';
 private uid = '';
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private as: AuthService) {
   as.afAuth.user.subscribe(user => {
     this.uid = user.uid; 
     console.log(this.uid); //result: '12312313'(id of user)
   });
   this.userFormsRef = db.list(this.uid + '/' + this.dbPath);
   console.log(this.uid);  // result: '' (nothing)
 }
```

Such as 'uid' is null, my further code doesn't work properly. It seems like angular didn't really assign user's id to this.uid. So how can i do it correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not whether your `this.uid` gets set, but **when** it gets set. You can most easily see this by adding some logging:

```
 private dbPath = '/pages';
 private uid = '';
 constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private as: AuthService) {
   console.log('before subscribing');
   as.afAuth.user.subscribe(user => {
     console.log('got uid');
     this.uid = user.uid; 
     console.log(this.uid); //result: '12312313'(id of user)
   });
   console.log('after subscribing');
   this.userFormsRef = db.list(this.uid + '/' + this.dbPath);
 }
```

When you run this code it prints:

> before subscribing

> after subscribing

> got uid

This may not be the order you expected, but it is working as designed. Since user data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, you main code continues to run. Then when the user data is available, your callback is executed.

So by the time your `db.list(this.uid + '/' + this.dbPath)` runs, the `this.uid = user.uid` hasn't run yet. For this reason, any code that needs the user data, needs to be inside the callback, or be called from there.

Something like this:

```
 private dbPath = '/pages';
 private uid = '';
 constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private as: AuthService) {
   as.afAuth.user.subscribe(user => {
     this.uid = user.uid; 
     this.userFormsRef = db.list(this.uid + '/' + this.dbPath);
   });
 }
```

Also see:

- [Displaying data from Firebase on load of Ionic app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49000884/displaying-data-from-firebase-on-load-of-ionic-app/49001026#49001026)
- [Auth with multiple firebase realtime databases on web not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60340766/auth-with-multiple-firebase-realtime-databases-on-web-not-working/60341607#60341607)
- [Using Firebase, firebase.auth().currentUser is a null value even though it is being logged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395996/using-firebase-firebase-auth-currentuser-is-a-null-value-even-though-it-is-be/46397739#46397739)

Comment: This is a great explaination , now my code works well/